# Metronome pendulum

Tags: waves, kinematics, torque, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

What is the formula for a metronome pendulum?

Answer (score 1):

A metronome pendulum is actually a very regular pendulum. The image below, taken from [this question about metronome on StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380856) shows that a metronome is a pendulum with two weights instead of one. Of Course, you need to consider

$$m_1 < m_2$$

in order for the pendulum to oscillate. You will find in the very same question the equation for the angular frequency of a metronome (with detailed steps).

[image: metronome pendulum scheme]