# Double weighted pendulum of a metronome

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, moment-of-inertia

[image]

Recently I have been studying about the pendulum and had an investigation of the double weighted pendulum of the metronome. Referring to the diagram in the following site, I have some parts that I don't understand and could you explain them?
[How does a metronome allow such a wide range of tempos in such a short distance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380856/how-does-a-metronome-allow-such-a-wide-range-of-tempos-in-such-a-short-distance)

The following is my best try of the interpretation of the problem:

$$
T=rFsin
$$
$$
T_{m2}=l_{2}m_{2}gsin
$$
$$
T_{m1}=l_{1}m_{1}gsin
$$
$$
T_{net}=l_{2}m_{2}gsin-l_{1}m_{1}gsin
$$

$$
I=mr^2
$$
$$
I_{m2}=m_{2}l_{2}^2
$$
$$
I_{m1}=m_{1}l_{1}^2
$$
$$
I_{Total}=m_{2}l_{2}^2+m_{1}l_{1}^2
$$

$$
T=Iα
$$
$$
l_{2}m_{2}gsin-l_{1}m_{1}gsin=(m_{2}l_{2}^2+m_{1}l_{1}^2)α
$$

$$
α= \frac{l_{2}m_{2}gsin-l_{1}m_{1}gsin}{(m_{2}l_{2}^2+m_{1}l_{1}^2)}
$$
small angle
$$
α= \frac{l_{2}m_{2}g-l_{1}m_{1}g}{(m_{2}l_{2}^2+m_{1}l_{1}^2)}
$$

My first confusion is how do I know whether it is $T_{m2}-T_{m1}$ or $T_{m1}-T_{m2}$

My second question is how does the process from angular acceleration to angular frequency work? I only know the fact time derivative of angular frequency is angular acceleration. Can someone do a detailed math of how angular acceleration convert to angular frequency, consequently deriving the angular frequency equation in the website? (I have a limited understanding in time derivative, sorry.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PhysicsSE! Questions shouldn't completely rely on links. Could you provide an image or a description of your issue?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti Thank you! I have added an image.

Comment: When working with a rotation, you choose a direction (along the axis) as positive. Then the vector representing a torque or other rotational quantity is positive or negative as determined by a right hand rule (generally fingers curled in the direction of rotation, vector in the direction of the thumb).

Answer (score 0):

Your system is basically a physical pendulum. The net torque is proportional to – sin(θ) and the angular acceleration is $d^2 θ/dt^2$.  For small angles, sin(θ) is almost equal to θ in radians and the differential equation solves to a sine function with an angular frequency, ω.  Look up the derivation for a simple or physical pendulum.